# 1-N strange error generate in C++ template partial specification, why?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, template-specialization

I have do some experiments and receive strange error message. In the provided code there are a bug in line 9 which will bring limit of recursion during template substitution but both compilers (logs of GCC 4.8.2 and CLANG 3.4 placed at the bottom) report

"no type named T".

I would appreciate if anyone can explain compilers strange messages.

Thanks.

```
typedef unsigned long size_t;
template<class _T, size_t _N>
struct P;
template<class _T>
struct P<_T, 0> {
    using T= _T;
};
template<class _T, size_t _N>
struct P {
    using T= typename P<_T, 1-_N>::T*; // instead of 1-_N will be _N-1
};
int main(void) {
    using namespace my;
    using namespace std;

    typedef P<int, 0>::T P0; // Ok
    typedef P<int, 1>::T P1; // Ok
    typedef P<int, 2>::T P2; // Error
    typedef P<int, 3>::T P2; // Error
    return 0;
}
```

> ```
> -------------- Build: (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler)---------------
>
> g++ -std=c++11 -Wall -fexceptions -Weffc++ -pedantic -std=c++11 -g  -c
> : In instantiation of ‘struct P<int, 18446744073709551615ul>’:
> :10:42:   required from ‘struct P<int, 2ul>’
> :15:26:   required from here
> :10:42: error: no type named ‘T’ in ‘struct P<int, 2ul>’
>          using T= typename P<_T, 1-_N>::T*; // instead of 1-_N will be _N-1
>                                           ^
> : In instantiation of ‘struct P<int, 18446744073709551614ul>’:
> :10:42:   required from ‘struct P<int, 3ul>’
> :16:26:   required from here
> :10:42: error: no type named ‘T’ in ‘struct P<int, 3ul>’
> Process terminated with status 1 (0 minute(s), 0 second(s))
> 2 error(s), 6 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s))
>
>
> -------------- Build: (compiler: LLVM Clang Compiler)---------------
>
> clang++ -std=c++11 -Wall -fexceptions  -pedantic -std=c++11 -g -Weffc++     -c
> :10:40: error: no type named 'T' in 'P<int, 2>'
>         using T= typename P<_T, 1-_N>::T*; // instead of 1-_N will be _N-1
>                  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^
> :10:27: note: in instantiation of template class 'P<int, 18446744073709551615>' requested here
>         using T= typename P<_T, 1-_N>::T*; // instead of 1-_N will be _N-1
>                           ^
> :15:17: note: in instantiation of template class 'P<int, 2>' requested here
>         typedef P<int, 2>::T P2; // Error
>                 ^
> :10:40: error: no type named 'T' in 'P<int, 3>'
>         using T= typename P<_T, 1-_N>::T*; // instead of 1-_N will be _N-1
>                  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^
> :10:27: note: in instantiation of template class 'P<int, 18446744073709551614>' requested here
>         using T= typename P<_T, 1-_N>::T*; // instead of 1-_N will be _N-1
>                           ^
> :16:17: note: in instantiation of template class 'P<int, 3>' requested here
>         typedef P<int, 3>::T P2; // Error
>                 ^
> 2 errors generated.
> Process terminated with status 1 (0 minute(s), 0 second(s))
> 2 error(s), 4 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s))
> ```

Comment: Why are you redefining [`size_t`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/size_t)? It's a standard type in C++.

Comment: It just for have complete sample without std included.

Comment: If you want a *complete* sample, then you should create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), which would contain a complete and compilable program, including header file includes.

Comment: Thank you for link. I have see
and it seems my sample is satisfy minimal completness.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that `(1 - (1 - N)) == N`.
As compiler states:

`struct P<int, 2ul>` depends of `struct P<int, 18446744073709551615ul>` which depends again of `struct P<int, 2ul>` (where `T` is still not defined (as itself with 2 pointers...)).

Answer (score 3):

size_t is an unsigned integer type, when instantiate the template with 2 (`P<int, 2>::T`), and perform **1-_N** calculation in `P<_T, 1-_N>::T*`, this result in _std::numeric_limits::max() - 1_ which is a really big number, and then when instantiating again `P<_T, 1-_N>::T*` result in the first instantiation (*with 2*) which is instantiating, in this case clang and gcc should be detecting that this particular instantiation is taking place an the type T is not known already (and never will, as it would generate and infinite cycle of instantiations).

Comment: Thank you for so quick response.
Yes of course the problem related with limit,but both compilers does not mention about limit, thats why I open this question:)

Comment: Yes if _N will be big enough it also will reach the limits.
The aim of code is pointer of pointer in N times, and the problem is how avoid limit related issue.

Comment: There is only 2 template instantiations for `P<int, 2>`, but `P<int, 2>::T` depends of `P<int, 2>::T`...

Comment: With this goal you should not reach the template instantiation limit.